How to validate code repos movement for tags, commit history etc
Our source repos currently is in Bitbucket. ~10 years of code checkin's it has.
We are moving our code to Gitlab now.
Pipeline fixes are NOT part of the current movement plan still how do we ensure/ validate that code movement is a success? Structure, Tags, Commit History, branches are correctly migrated and each branches structure, tags, commit history etc..?
Any git commands that we can run, after migration, both on source and target repos to help us validate?
We have >100 repos to be migrated..

If the git commit id hash of your main/master branch's HEAD in the source and destination repos are identical then that's all the proof you need (yay Merkel Trees) that all preceding data was moved-over correctly - so after that just ensure all branch names (and their head commit-ids) exist in both repos, ditto for tags.

There’s nothing to validate for Git objects/refs if you trust git(1). It will do the right thing. It’s a slightly longer story if you don’t trust git(1).
